# How to extract points off a polyline at certain distances using ArcObjects using VB.Net

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to extract longitude and latitude of points from a polyline shapefile at certain intervals(10-50m). Using ArcGIS I was able to do using Densify followed by Feature Vertices to Points in Data Management Tools. But while doing so in VB.Net I am not able to locate this Class FeatureVerticesToPoints in VB.NET thus making my process useless.

1. Is it possible to use these ArcGIS tools in VB.NET using ArcObjects and in case yes, How?
2. Also, is there any other better method to do this?
3. Can someone help me with a code of something similar as I am a beginner to programming using ArcObjects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IGeoProcessor to call any of the geoprocessing tools, have a look at his [page](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/c4ff8b68-0410-435f-b8e5-682d5cea47cf.htm).

Having said that you have asked for an alternative method. I would have used [Ipolyline.QueryPointAndDistance()](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/ICurve_QueryPointAndDistance.htm) and extracted points out along a single polyline.

Comment: Also see `IGeometry.Project` so you can juggle between decimal degrees and xy coordinates in a projection valid for measuring lengths.